# How to Split string into words in c#

Tags: c#

How can I split the following string to words

`string  exp=price+10*discount-30`

into

`string[] words={'price',discount' }`

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Please explain in more detail what you want to achieve. It's hard to tell right now what you want to do.

Comment: Please define what you mean by "words". Are "string" and "exp" not words? Also, is `string exp...` a declaration in C# code? Then why is the right part not a valid string? Or is this your string, as in `string s = "string exp=price+10*discount-30"`?

Comment: How do you define a "word"? It may be possible to solve this problem if you can be clear about such a definition.

Comment: There are quite a few examples you may want to look at and try, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159026/regex-how-to-get-words-from-a-string-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could match words with regex and then get the results.

example:

```
        // This is the input string.
        string input = "price+10*discount-30";

        var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"([a-z]+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
        foreach (var match in matches)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: we can do same thing like this   string[] words = Regex.Split(inputstring, @"\W+");

Answer (score 0):

Hope this example helps:

```
string str = "price+10*discount-30";
char[] delimiters = new char[] { '+', '1', '0', '*', '-', '3'};
string[] parts = str.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (string s in parts)
    Console.WriteLine(s);

Console.ReadLine();
```

Output is:

```
price
discount
```

Comment: if the above is to work with any numbers, then after the forloop you could check for a `Double.TryParse(s)` so that numbers are not read into it.

Answer (score 0):

what you want is a lexer, that tokenizes words depending on type of input. Here is a little program that does this for you.

```
        int dummy;
        string data = "string price = 10 * discount + 12";
        string[] words = data.Split(' ');
        LinkedList<string> tokens = new LinkedList<string>();
        LinkedList<string> keywords = new LinkedList<string>();
        LinkedList<string> operators = new LinkedList<string>();
        keywords.AddLast("string");
        operators.AddLast("*");
        operators.AddLast("/");
        operators.AddLast("+");
        operators.AddLast("=");
        operators.AddLast("-");
        foreach (string s in words)
        {
            if (keywords.Contains(s)) continue;
            if (operators.Contains(s)) continue;
            if (int.TryParse(s, out dummy) == true) continue;
            tokens.AddLast(s.Trim());
        }
        string[] data_split = tokens.ToArray();
```