# How to put contents of a file into an array using vanilla Javascript?

Tags: javascript, file, random

I would like to know if there is a possibility to get the text content of a file and transform it in a string or array, so that I can get random words from it.

I have to solve the following coding challenge in Javascript:

> **
>
> > A program that randomly displays words from a text.
>
> > 1.) Read a text file with a lot of content and randomly output a certain number of words
>
> Example:
>
> *enter how many words you want: 5
>
> > Output: anything acceptance shall and EVEN*

**

I manage to write a code that displays a text on the page, but I can't think of a solution to get the content and get random words from it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Random Tweet Generator</title>
    
    <input type="file" name="inputfile" id="inputfile">
    <br>
   
    <pre id="output"></pre>
    
    <style>
     
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Random Tweet Generator</h1>
    <script>
        document.getElementById('inputfile')
        .addEventListener('change', function() {

        let fr=new FileReader();
        fr.onload=function(){
        document.getElementById('output')
        .textContent=fr.result;
        }

        fr.readAsText(this.files[0]);
        })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show an example of what the file contains.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can prompt the user for a number.
2. You can run a regex match on the returned text [that looks for words](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2159085/1377002). This will return an array.
3. You can then use a loop from zero to the prompted number, splicing out random word from the array and logging it. Note that [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) returns an array so you need to access the first element.

```js
const output = document.getElementById('output');
const input = document.getElementById('inputfile');
input.addEventListener('change', handleChange, false);

const numberOfWords = +prompt('How many words?');

function randomNumber(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - 0) + 0);
}

function handleChange() {

  // The regex to match words
  const regex = /\w(?<!\d)[\w'-]*/g;
  let fr = new FileReader();
  fr.onload = function () {

    // Produce an array of words in the file
    const arr = fr.result.match(regex);

    // From 0 to the numberOfWords
    // get a random number based on the length of the array
    // splice a word out and log it
    for (let i = 0; i < numberOfWords; i++) {
      const rnd = randomNumber(arr.length);
      const word = arr.splice(rnd, 1);
      console.log(word[0].toLowerCase());
    }
  }
  fr.readAsText(this.files[0]);
}
```

```html
<input type="file" name="inputfile" id="inputfile">
<br>
<pre id="output"></pre>
<h1>Random Tweet Generator</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are reading a text file, then

```
fr.onload=function()
{
 let text  = fr.result;
 let lines = text.split("\r\n");       
}
```

will split the file into lines. Now you could randomly pick a line from the file by

```
let randomline = lines[Math.floor((Math.random() * lines.length))];
```

But of course, how you "cut" the files into pieces is up to you.
Want to split by, say, spaces?

```
let words      = text.split(" ");
let randomword = words[Math.floor((Math.random() * words.length))];
```

Long story short, there's no definite answer to your question, but here are some hints on how to move on.